# Behavior of ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I have passed the HTTPS certificate following the steps documented in Microsoft's article, [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-focal
using

- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:Development
- ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT:"8001"
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password:xxx
- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path:

I always get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

It only works if I read the values and added them to

```
builder.UseKestrel()
  .ConfigureKestrel(options => {
    options.AddServerHeader = false;
    if (isHttps) {
      options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, DefaultPort, listenOptions => {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(
           CertificateFilePath,
           CertificatePassword
        );
      });
    }
  });
```

I am a bit confused about the difference between the two approaches and when to use which. It's the same certificate, the same configurations, but Kestrel never picks it up using only the environment variables. I don't have `launchSettings.json` in my Docker image, is this the issue?

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following in docker file

user:  "ContainerAdministrator"